# Djaty - Why the affected users count is not accurate when using `Djaty.setUser()`?

Tags: javascript, djaty

I'm installing Djaty Javascript SDK on one of my projects. It's installed properly now and I'm trying to use `Djaty.setUser()`

I want to set all possible user information so I'm using `Djaty.setUser()` into my code at two places. First place to set `userId` and the second place to set the user `logon`.

First place:

```
Djaty.setUser({userId: user.userId})
```

Second place:

```
Djaty.setUser({logon: user.username})
```

When I create a test bug I expect the bug to have only one affected user but actually it has two users now. What's the problem with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, calling `Djaty.setUser` multiple times will override the contextual user object everytime. For example, calling it in the order you mentioned will lead to an object with only the `logon` property.

Regarding your problem, the following scenario can lead to it:

```
if (isUserLogonAvailable) {
  Djaty.setUser({logon: user.username});
} else {
  Djaty.setUser({userId: user.userId});
}

app.notExistingMethod();
```

When the `isUserLogonAvailable` flag is true, the `app.notExistingMethod()` bug occurrence will have the contextual user as `{userId: user.username, logon: user.username}` because if the `userId` doesn't exist, we fallback to the `logon`. Similarly, when the code is executed again with `isUserLogonAvailable` flag is false, another bug occurrence will be submitted but the contextual user will be `{userId: user.userId, logon: user.userId}`.

Now your bug occurrences have two different users:

1- `userId`: `user.username`

2- `userId`: `user.userId`

And this results in the two affected users you ask about.

Comment: Exactly, this is the case. Thank you!